# Oracle FOR ALL update doesn't work for random partitions (within SAS 4gl)

Tags: oracle, sas

Here's the process i'm executing: (it's all done within SAS 4gl code)

1. Reading ID column and a 16-digit long varchar2(128) column (Credit card number) from a single partition from a partitioned table (new partition is created each day, so there are no performance issues)
2. Using a proc groovy and some simple 4gl transoformations i'm creating a temporary table in oracle DB with the ID column and a 128-character long hash representing the credit card number.
3. Using a cursor and the FOR ALL i am updating the original table with new card number values(hashed ones).

I ran this last night for 900 partitions. Today i checked the outcome and it turns out that 60 partitions were not updated. These partitions are not consecutive, really seems like random ones. There were no errors in SAS, no errors in Oracle, no DB restarts.

I tried running the same code for those 60 partitions but nothing changed. (again no errors)

Then i tried updating one partition out of these 60 with the same code. I even queried the temporary table im creating and the number of records matched with the number of records that require update and all the Card Numbers were a 128-character long hashes in the TEMP which means the code works up untill this point so i guess the problem is with updating the original table.

I'm not an oracle expert, so maybe there is something i'm missing here, but the fact that the code worked fine for over 800 partitions in this table and over 3000 partitions total in other tables tells me it's correct.

I've already asked our DB admins for help but it might take some time and im curious :)

Is there a possibility of corrupted oracle partitions/blocks that would not cause an error while accesing/modyfing them?

If so, then how do i know if a partition/block is corrupted?

@EDIT...

I have solved the problem. Table contains multiple duplicates on these partitions and thus why rows are not getting updated.

Comment: Please update your question to provide an example of your code. It really sounds like you could do this all in a single UPDATE/MERGE statement, rather than needing cursor/forall; my guess is there's something about your looping that is missing off rows.

Comment: Have you tried the same processing with sql code in `Proc FEDSQL` instead of through your java in `GROOVY` ?  Can you post the java code ?

Comment: I've updated the question with solution after analysis of the partitions. Thanks for quick reaction though :)